# python: найти слово в txt и вывести вторую строку

Tags: python

```
with open('C:\файл.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    if slovo in line:
        print(second line)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   line = f.readlines()

   for key, val in enumerate(line):
      if 'slovo' in val:
         print(line[key + 1])
```

Метод readlines() читает файл и получает список строк, с соответствующей возможностью работы со списками и строками.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Понял. Буду иметь в виду.

Comment: тут скорее не `key, val`, а `index, content`...

Comment: @Jack_oS, согласен, да.